# Using the same variable name for a function's argument and its return value*

Tags: php

In

```
public function bind($query, $input_param, $btypes)
{
    // $input_param = $this->ref_arr($input_param);  // this self assignment gives an error!
    $input_ref = $this->ref_arr($input_param);       // this works 
}
```

I learned this by trial and error... but I'm trying to figure out why?

I haven't had a chance to form more test cases but if I use `$input_param` as in input to the function I can not return the result back to `$input_param`. Once I change the name to something else, in this case `$input_ref` it works.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Can you try to clean it up a bit?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Does it give you an error? And what does `ref_arr()` look like?

Comment: Based on code shown here, as far as I can tell both of those should work, so the issue is most likely elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$this` keyword references the current object you are in.

So if you are in code that is in a class like this:

```
class foo {
   public function __construct() {
      $this->bar = 'that'; // works because $this references the foo object
   }
}
```

Should work. In the case where you are outside of an object however, `$this` would not work, because there is no object for `$this` to reference.

```
class foo {
   public function __construct() {

   }
}
$this->bar = 'that'; // will not work because you are not inside of any object
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to reproduce this...simply changing the variable name fixed the problem.